# uproot: allowed operations between TH2D histograms

Tags: uproot

I am trying to translate my data analysis workflow into python from C++. I have a very basic question: I have loaded two TH2D objects, unstuck them, and now I want to perform some operations between them (eg. sum/add, normalised difference, etc..): which is the best way to proceed in python? Where can I find the methods associated with the class TH2D (with inheritances) in uproot?

In particular, how would those operations work when the index and column are of the type `IntervallIndex` with `+inf` and `-inf` as `.right` and/or `.left` values?

Right now I am trying to process the `uproot.rootio.TH2D` into NumPy and/or pandas, but the structure of the original TH2D is lost.

Thank you :)